# Twitter Embedded Tweets Remove @reply

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, tweets

Im trying to [embed a tweet](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets) using twitter new embedded tweets but I dont want the @reply to show. Im hoping to embed multiple tweets from the same conversation but dont want redundant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.twt-actions { display: none; }` to your CSS, this will remove 'reply', 'retweet' and 'favorite' actions.