# Remove follow button from embedded tweet

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter

I'm embedding tweet on a website and I would like to remove the follow button and also the *reply*, *favorite* and *retweet* buttons that are in the footer. A minimal HTML example is the following

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/StackCareers/statuses/468107750333894656"></a>
</blockquote>
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

By inspecting the code, once the tweet is diplayed, I figured that the button is wrapped as following

```
<a class="follow-button profile" href="https://twitter.com/StackCareers" role="button" data-scribe="component:followbutton" title="Follow StackOverflowCareers on Twitter"><i class="ic-button-bird"></i>Follow</a>
```

So far I tried to remove this class using JQuery

```
$('.follow-button.profile').remove()
```

I also tried to overwrite the css by adding the following line to my stylesheet :

```
.follow-button {visibility:hidden;}
```

And following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635579/twitter-embedded-tweets-remove-reply), I tried adding also this line

```
.twt-actions { display: none; }
```

None of the above worked. Is there a solution to customize these embedded tweets ?

Comment: `$('.follow-button.profile').remove()` works fine. As does `.follow-button {visibility:hidden;}`. Maybe it's in an iframe?

Comment: I used the Chrome code inspector and typed `$('.follow-button.profile').remove()` in the console, it is saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null`. I also tried to add this query just after loading the twitter javascript, no luck so far. Can you please provide a minimal example as an answer ?

Comment: You are right, it is indeed in a `iframe`. How can I remove objects in an iframe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You are loading cross-domain content into an iframe from a source with a same-origin policy, which means you cannot manipulate the contents from your Javascript.

As far as I am aware, there is no out-of-the-box embed code for tweets that doesn't use an iframe.

You have two options. The first option is to display the tweet as it is provided. The second options is to [use the API to retrieve the tweet](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/:id) and display it as you please. For the latter, you'll have to sign up for an API key.

Alternatively, you may be able to find a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076648) but I can't vouch for the quality of any implementation of any of these suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm already retrieving tweets from the API. I ended up copying the twitter css style and displayed it as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to do this with the `widget` that returns a `Shadow DOM element`. I read [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/) that you can manipulate `CSS` from `shadow elements`. The `Twitter Widget` defines a `Shadow element` that, in my case where I just have one tweet embedded, has an id: `#twitter-widget-0`. 
So, I put the following in my `CSS`:

```
  #twitter-widget-0::shadow div.Tweet-brand {
   display: none;
  }
```

I hope it's useful!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple different ways to embed tweets - according to the [docs on embedding tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/overview):

> Our widget scans the DOM on execution, converting `blockquote.twitter-tweet` elements into fully-rendered embedded Tweets based on element content.
>
> To directly render an embedded Tweet at runtime use the [`twttr.widgets.createTweet()`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/embedded-tweet-javascript-factory-function) function.

#### a) Default Through Publish Widget

If you process [this tweet](https://twitter.com/KyleMitBTV/status/1188837207206977536) through the [publish widget](https://publish.twitter.com), it will generate the following code ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/hLqc1eyw/)):

```html
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
  <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Nobody:<br><br>Software Marketing Page: "Blazingly Fast"</p>
  &mdash; Kyle Mitofsky (@KyleMitBTV) 
  <a href="https://twitter.com/KyleMitBTV/status/1188837207206977536">October 28, 2019</a>
</blockquote>
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Then, you *could* go identify all the `<twitter-widget>` elements that were created and update any style properties in their `shadowRoot` like this:

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName('twitter-widget')].forEach(tweet => { 
  let style = tweet.shadowRoot.firstElementChild;
  let css = document.createTextNode(`.EmbeddedTweet .CallToAction { display: none; }`);
  style.appendChild(css);
})
```

However, we have to wait until the widget has processed each tweet and I can't find an event to tap into that would allow you to fire this at the right time (without doing some weird `setTimeout` stuff and hoping you waited long enough

#### b) Manually through JavaScript

You can take over the creation of the tweet like this:

```js
let tweetId = "1188837207206977536"
let tweetContainer = document.getElementById('tweet-container');
twttr.widgets.createTweet(tweetId, tweetContainer)
```

Which will return a promise that you can handle as soon as the tweet has been inserted, allowing you to update styles in the `shadowRoot` like this ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/rc3L7a5x/)):

```html
<div id="tweet-container" class="embedded-tweets"></div>
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  let tweetId = "1188837207206977536"
  let tweetContainer = document.getElementById('tweet-container');
  twttr.widgets.createTweet(tweetId, tweetContainer)
       .then(function (tweet) {
         let style = tweet.shadowRoot.firstElementChild;
         let css = document.createTextNode(`.EmbeddedTweet .CallToAction { display: none; }`);
         style.appendChild(css);
       });
</script>
```

> **Note**: The Tweet ID must be a string as numbers above `253 - 1 = 9007199254740991` in JavaScript will be truncated ([`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER))

#### Notes on Shadow DOM

The `<twitter-widget>` is a [web component](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components) that is styled using the [shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom).  Global style overrides using `/deep/` or `::shadow` were deprecated in Chrome 45 and [removed in Chrome 63](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/remove-shadow-piercing).  Currently the best way to [override styles in shadow root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47625017/1366033) is to set a `style` element directly in the element's `shadowRoot`

Answer (score 1):

in case you have multiple widgets

```
<style>

  [id*="twitter-widget"]::shadow div.Tweet-brand {   display: none;  }

</style>
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this for an embedded video?