# Ionic 4 change input color

Tags: css, ionic-framework, shadow-dom, css-variables, ionic4

I am trying to simply change the color of a text/password input.  Unfortunately, everything to be able to change is hidden behind the `#shadow-root` so my CSS can't touch it.

I've tried to simply write:

```
input {
  color:var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}
```

but of course it does not see anything inside the shadow realm.  the HTML is laid out like so:

```
<ion-input _ngcontent-c0="" class="form__group__item--input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid hydrated ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-invalid has-focus" formcontrolname="email" type="text" ng-reflect-name="email" ng-reflect-type="text">
    #shadow-root
        <style></style
        <input> // Need to edit this one
        <slot></slot?
    <input type="hidden" class="aux-input" name="ion-input-0" value="">
</ion-input>
```

The css that's controlling the color of the input is not using a variable that I'm able to change anywhere else

```
input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 11px system-ui;
}
```

but I'm not able to override those.  I feel like I need to do something in the root, but I don't know CSS variables yet.

is there any way in Ionic 4 to change the input text color??

Comment: Can you not just apply the color style to `ion-input` itself or a class on it?

Comment: @JosephWebber I have tried that, but ion-input does not send its styles down the chain into the `#shadow-root`

Answer (score 4):

Doing a quick Google search brought up [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/#toc-style-cat-hat) site which explains you can use the `::shadow` pseudo-element to style elements within shadow trees, so try this

```css
ion-input::shadow input {
  color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

**Edit:**

Doing some more digging around I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625017/override-styles-in-a-shadow-root-element) SO post  which says you can't style things inside the shadow DOM with global CSS, so you need to instead create and append a `style` tag to the host.

```js
// host is the element that holds the shadow root:
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = '.the-class-name { property-name: my-value; }';
host.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: ::shadow is deprecated

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: @JosephWebber, Thank you for the updated answer.  I'm going to play with this and report back when I'm able to.  I was hoping to avoid any javascript, but if that's the only way...

Answer (score 1):

Native input in ionic4 inherits text color so you just have to set css color of `ion-input`.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-input placeholder="Muhahaaaa"></ion-input>
```

**CSS:**

```
ion-input {
    --placeholder-color: green;     /* placeholder text color */
    color: var(--ion-color-primary; /* input text color to primary */
}
```

**Reference to ionic code (4.0.0-beta.11):**

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/input/input.scss#L43