# How to remove small caret from ion-select in ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I want to remove the inbuilt grey small caret from `ion-select`, and use my 
custom caret(arrow) instead.

Code:

```
ion-select {
  color: grey;
  background:url("/assets/resources/img/ArrowDownConfig.svg");
}
```

But my css code is unable to precedence over the ionic(inbuilt).

You can see there are two arrows in the image, one is inbuilt and another is custom. I want to remove inbuilt(ionic) one.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've created [this](https://gist.github.com/Sroose/3d8a25b469ecc4e556558d5caa986be1) directive which you can add to your ion-select to make it look just like other ion elements with placeholder (without arrow).

Usage:

```
<ion-select placeholder="Choose" appNoArrow>...
```

Answer (score 18):

To remove the icon,

```
 ion-select::part(icon) {
    display: none !important;
   }
```

To modify the icon,

```
  ion-select::part(icon) {
    color: #ffa612 !important;
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is working for Ionic 5. Actually I am using "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.4" and it's working fine.

Comment: I meant... That this doesn’t work for Ionic 4 or less. Only does for Ionic 5 or more.

Comment: BTW, if you use a floating label, you should use `width: 0` instead of `display:none`

Answer (score 11):

If you want just remove the carets, you can do this:

```js
// ...other page methods

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    const ionSelects = document.querySelectorAll('ion-select');
    ionSelects.forEach((sel) => {
      sel.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.select-icon-inner')
        .forEach((elem) => {
          elem.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
        });
    });
  }
```

> Based on [@Sangminem response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55868286/7242535)

In addition, in my case, I'm using `slot="end"` with an `ion-icon` to place a replacement icon:

```html
<ion-item lines="inset">
  <ion-label position="floating">Label</ion-label>

  <ion-select>
    <ion-select-option value="1">Option 1</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="2">Option 2</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="2">Option 3</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>

  <ion-icon color="danger" slot="end" name="arrow-dropdown-circle" class="ion-align-self-center"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: BTW, if you use a floating label, you should set `width: 0` style  instead of `display:none`

Comment: For Ionic 5, you should use this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62851330/7242535

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to fix, faced same problem, but it seems to be issue with [DOM Shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)

If you will find anything, let to know as well please, thanks.

Update:
Found some [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47633167/3789381)

UPDATE #2

I created directive in order to have access to Shadow DOM and it's able to add styles into isolated DOM.

HTML:

```
 <ion-select appStyle>
```

Directive(need to find better implementation):

```
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.el.nativeElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('.select-icon-inner').setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important');
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are several ion-select items, here is a sample.

TS Code :

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    // ion-select customizing
    const ionSelects = document.querySelectorAll('ion-select');
    let img = null;
    ionSelects.forEach((ionSelect) => {
      const selectIconInner = ionSelect.shadowRoot.querySelector('.select-icon').querySelector('.select-icon-inner');
      if(selectIconInner){
        selectIconInner.attributes.removeNamedItem("class");
        img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "./new-arrow-down-image.svg";
        img.style.width = "12px";
        img.style.paddingTop = "3px";
        img.style.paddingLeft = "4px";
        img.style.color = "black";
        img.style.opacity = "0.5";
        selectIconInner.appendChild(img);
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to remove default *icon* with css, using `::part` directive:

```css
&::part(icon) {
    display: none;
}
```

and the arrow disappear.

Comment: BTW, if you use a floating label, you should use `width: 0` instead of `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

`.select-icon-inner {
    border-top: transparent!important;}`

I think this is only possible with ioni3. If you want to solve only css in ionic4, you need to know the exact class name of select-icon in ionic4

Answer (score 0):

To modify the icon, call this function

```
async removeSelectCaret(id){
    const select = await (window.document.querySelector(`#${id}`) as HTMLIonSelectElement).componentOnReady();
    select.shadowRoot.childNodes[1]['style'].display="none";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quite the icon of ion-select-option only add mode="ios" on

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic 4, does not support ::part selector, so we could not hide the caret by CSS.
I have a idea to hide the icon that adding a layer on-top and overlap the caret icon, use same background color with ion-select

```
ion-select {
  &.hide-caret {
    opacity: 1;
    &::after {
      content: ' ';
      width: 40px;
      height: 100%;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ion-select class="hide-caret" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
setTimeout(() => {
    const ionSelects = document.querySelectorAll('ion-select');
    // const ionSelects:any =  document.getElementsByClassName('phoselect');
    let img = null;
    ionSelects.forEach((ionSelect) => {
      const selectIconInner = ionSelect.shadowRoot.querySelector('.select-icon').querySelector('.select-icon-inner');
      if(selectIconInner){
        let _cs=`right: 5px;left:0px; top: 100%;margin-top: -3px;`
        selectIconInner.setAttribute("style",_cs)
         
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To modify the icon , you can try something like this :
`.select-icon-inner {
    border-top: transparent!important;
}`