# Ionic 4 ion-select set custom icon for select-icon

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to set a custom icon to ion-select. Following is my code and output

```html
<ion-item class="input-container" align-items-center no-padding>
  <ion-label position="floating" no-margin no-padding>I am a</ion-label>
  <ion-select formControlName="role" mode="ios" okText="Okay" cancelText="Cancel">
    <ion-select-option value="Admin">Admin</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="Customer">Customer</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
  <ion-icon color="primary" name="arrow-down" mode="ios" slot="end"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

[image]

Is there any other way of set custom icon or can anyone suggest a way tohow to remove `select-icon-inner`

Comment: do you want to set the blue one instead the grey?

Comment: Yes. I need to have blue one. It is my custom icon

Comment: This is a bit tricky one currently. I would suggest creating a directive for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55303341/6294072 Unfortunately doesn't seem to be a better option currently.

Answer (score 8):

You can override the content of the icon part. This worked for me, just go with:

```css
ion-select::part(icon) {
  content: url('your-icon-path/your-icon.svg');
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-cun2mj?file=styles.css)  working example

Comment: Works well! This should be the accepted answer. It seems like the most correct way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

In ionic v4 a workaround is hiding the icon through .scss file.

```css
ion-select::part(icon) {
  display: none !important;
}

ion-select::part(text) {
  background-image: url(<ImageUrl>);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in i5:

```
ion-select::part(icon) {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 1em;
  color: transparent;
  background: url('assets/icons/light-mode/expand-down.svg') no-repeat center;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not a proper solution but still, it can fix this problem.
Apply this style in .scss file -

```
ion-select {
  min-width: 100vw;
}
```