# Ionic 4 customize ion select

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, overriding, ionic4

I need to modify ion-select like [image: this] value is in left and the drop down arrow in right. it happens when i use google dev tools. but in code wherever it tried it won't work

1st i tried in using google console and this is the original one [image: this]

this is after modified [image: this]

then I tried to use this in app.scss

```
 ion-select
{
    .select-text{
          position: absolute !important;
          right:0 !important;
    }
}
```

But it won't happen.

Comment: in dev tools you see the class `.select-icon` but in your css, you use `.select-text`

Comment: Can you post your HTML code here? so we can get some idea what's going wrong with your code and CSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove small caret from ion-select in ionic4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300777/how-to-remove-small-caret-from-ion-select-in-ionic4)

Answer (score 3):

A solution to your problem applies `max-width` on your `ion-select` like below :

```
ion-select
{
  max-width: 95%;
}
```

use it as per your design requirement it will use the full width and show your select control as per your requirement.

By default, `ion-select` uses **45% width** that's why you are facing this issue.

Hope this will helps!

Comment: @LVW23 is above solution resolved your problem? if yes can you please accept this answer? so others can find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As you may know Ionic introduce Shadow root elements with new updates. You can change css from typescript. I found This solution for me.

[How to remove small caret from ion-select in ionic4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300777/how-to-remove-small-caret-from-ion-select-in-ionic4)