# Is it possible to add attribute to elements within shadow root?

Tags: javascript, attributes, shadow-dom

so i'm using javascript and what i've done is capture a nodeList of shadowroot buttons within a webpage. I need to add attributes to each of them. Is there a way to do so? I've done it to other elements (not shadowroot) by using the .attr() but it appears shadow-roots act differently?

An example of a previously used code I had that is non shadow-root is the following:

```
elements.eq(i).attr("custom-attr", "analytics-purposes-only" + 
elements.eq(i)..text().trim());
```

thank you in advanced.

also to note, this is my first time interacting with shadow-roots so things are new to me for this one.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: See first comment; And tell us what library you are using, the code you post is not native JavaScript syntax. If its jQuery, you better start with http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ first; jQuerys' selectors can't get into shadowRoots

Answer (score 0):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/54855079/9778755, you can use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) on an element, even within `shadowRoot`, e.g.:

```js
document.querySelector("my-custom-element").shadowRoot.querySelector("button").setAttribute("disabled", "")
```

Comment: Hi is it possible to add attributes on shadowRoot itself and not it's decedents?

Comment: No, the `ShadowRoot` does not have a `setAttribute` method: [ShadowRoot - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot). However, you might be referencing to the `ShadowRoot`'s host. This is the root `Element` and you can set attributes on it.