# CSS selector for font color in flextable with shadow host on

Tags: css, r, flextable

I'm unsuccessfully trying to set the font color for `flextable` generated in `r markdown` using a css stylesheet.

I can accomplish this when I turn off shadow host, but not with it on. (Just turning it off removes other desirable features.) Here's a short r markdown file demonstrating the difference.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

<style>
div.flextable-shadow-host * {
  color: pink;
}

div.tabwid * {
  color: pink;
}

</style>

# ignores CSS above

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(flextable)
flextable(head(mtcars))
```

# accepts CSS above

```{r, echo=FALSE}
ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
htmltools_value(ft, ft.shadow = FALSE)
```
````

I want the css external to the r code because I have a button selector on the website the user can change the overall style (e.g., dark mode or not).

Comment: Inspecting the html file, the flextable shadow does state indicate it's "open", and this stack overflow post suggests what I'm trying to accomplish is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625017/override-styles-in-a-shadow-root-element but I'm not that familiar with shadow trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `shadow`, the table is assembled outside of HTML. Only the `id` connects the table to HTML. However, `flextable` has functions for setting the color. Why not just use one of the many built-in methods to change the color?

For example:

````
# ignores CSS above

```{r liberator,include=F}
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)

```

```{r tbler, echo=FALSE}

flextable(head(mtcars)) %>% 
  color(color = "pink", part = "all")

```

# accepts CSS above

```{r, echo=FALSE}
ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
htmltools_value(ft, ft.shadow = FALSE)
```
````

[image]

There are many things you can do with `flextable` styling. [You can see more customization options here](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/format.html).

---

---

#### Update: Based on your comments

Okay, this works to change the color of a `flextable`.

> This works if there is only **one** `flextable` in the script.

I have the color of the text set to `#b21E29` (a shade of red). You can change that as you see fit.

##### These will SKIP non-shadow `flextables`

Add this chunk anywhere in your RMD script. This requires no additional libraries or any other customization in your R code.

````
```{r js_ing,results="asis",engine="js",echo=F}
// extract the styles that are set for the flextable
letMe = document.querySelector('div.flextable-shadow-host').shadowRoot.querySelector('div>style');

// replace color style
// preceding ';' so that 'background-color' doesn't change
letMe.innerHTML = letMe.innerHTML.replace(/;(color:.+?);/g, ';color:#b21e29 !important;');                
```
````

[image]

If you have more than one `flextable` with shadow on, you can use one of the two following chunks instead. In the first--all the same color; in the second--each table has a different color.

> These work if there is **more than one** `flextable` in the script.

Pay attention to the comments so you can see what to use when depending on your desired output.

All the same color:

````
```{r moreJs_ing,results="asis",engine="js",echo=F}
// collect all of the flextables with shadow
letMe = document.querySelectorAll('div.flextable-shadow-host');

// to set all shadow flextables to the same font color:
for(i = 0, n = letMe.length; i < n; i++){
  showMe = letMe[i].shadowRoot.querySelector('div>style');
  showMe.innerHTML = showMe.innerHTML.replace(/;(color:.+?);/g, ';color:#b21e29 !important;');
}
```
````

[image]

Each with there own color:

````
```{r evenMoreJs_ing,results="asis",engine="js",echo=F}
//alternatively to set each to a different color
// make sure you only include one of these options!

// collect all of the flextables with shadow
letMe = document.querySelectorAll('div.flextable-shadow-host');

// first table in script
showFirst = letMe[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('div>style');
showFirst.innerHTML = showFirst.innerHTML.replace(/;(color:.+?);/g, ';color:#b21e29 !important;');

// second table in script
showSecond = letMe[1].shadowRoot.querySelector('div>style');
showSecond.innerHTML = showSecond.innerHTML.replace(/;(color:.+?);/g, ';color:#003b70 !important;');


// change the indices for each table, keep in mind the first table is [0], not [1]
```
````

[image]

If you aren't sure where you want to go with these, add all three and and `include=F` as a chunk option to the two you aren't using at that moment in time.

Comment: Hi Kat, I need to be able to change the color after the html file is loaded based on a styling button that the user selects (e.g., changing to dark mode from regular: white background with black text changes to black background with white text), so using the built-in flextable function as you suggested won't work for dynamic changes.

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I missed the update, but thanks! I was able to use your js to get the effect I wanted, but it seems there should be a way to use straight css instead of a js selector, no?

Comment: Not in this case. There are at least two reasons: the styles are initially established with JS, and the content is a shadow. Think of it as a webpage within a webpage. Glad I could help!