# Changing background color on sticky multi-row flextable header

Tags: javascript, css, r, flextable

Hi there – below I have a scrolling flextable with multiple headers. Whenever I scroll, the table body text can be seen behind the table header (i.e., the table header is transparent). I'm looking for a way to set the table header background color to white.

I've tried utilizing the `extra_css` portion of the `set_table_properties` function – this worked to make the multiple headers "sticky", however the code for `background-color` is not generating white as desired. I've also tried adjusting the z-index, which hasn't worked either.

I saw that [utilizing Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70916362/css-selector-for-font-color-in-flextable-with-shadow-host-on) may be one solution, however I've been unsuccessful in applying this for my specific use case. Any suggestions on resolving this issue are greatly appreciated!

---

### title: "Untitled"
output: html_document

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)


tbl1 <- flextable(mtcars) %>%
  add_header_row(top = TRUE, values = c("","header 1", "header 2"), colwidths = c(1,5,5)) %>%
  set_table_properties(
    layout = "autofit",
    opts_html = list(
      scroll = list(
        height = "300px",
        freeze_first_column = F
      ),
      extra_css = "
          thead{
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: white;
          z-index: 99;
      }
      "
    )
  )
```

[What the table looks like after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D5as.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use function `bg()` for that:

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)


tbl1 <- flextable(mtcars) %>%
  bg(bg = "white", part = "all") %>% 
  add_header_row(top = TRUE, values = c("","header 1", "header 2"), colwidths = c(1,5,5)) %>%
  set_table_properties(
    layout = "autofit",
    opts_html = list(
      scroll = list(
        height = "300px",
        freeze_first_column = FALSE
      ),
      extra_css = "
          thead{
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
          z-index: 99;
      }
      "
    )
  )
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! (And thank you for this beautiful package. Wouldn't be able to do my job without it!!)