# How to apply styling to shadow root element in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, ng-deep

I am using angular 12 and I want to apply some styling to input field which is a shadow root element of **group-search-field** element.

[image]

I tried using ng-deep like below but it didn't work

```css
:host ::ng-deep input {
  background: red !important;
}
```

Can someone guide me for this ?

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786986/how-and-where-to-use-ng-deep

Comment: @Nick tried like this .search-field ::ng-deep input { background-color: red !important; } but did not work

Comment: hard to figure out. in your example above (the image) i cannot find .search-field

Comment: Maybe: .search-field ::ng-deep form input { background-color: red !important; } is running fine

Comment: search-field is the class of group-search-field (it's not in above image but I added later) so I am using same in ng-deep reference.

Comment: so form and input in under the shadow root and I am stumbling over same that how to build the path for the ng deep when element is under shadow root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override styles in a shadow-root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625017/override-styles-in-a-shadow-root-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the isolation of styles, which is a feature of Shadow DOM, you cannot define a global CSS rule that will be applied in the Shadow DOM scope. In your case I think `background:red` does not propagate to be inherited by the elements in the shadow root that's why `:host` is not working.

```js
super();
const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet;
sheet.replaceSync( `input { background: red !important; }`)
shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [ sheet ];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

Comment: and where should I add above piece of code considering angular ?

Comment: App component constructor should work.