# Browser ignoring css styles for id if the element hast additional classes

Tags: html, css

if i am having a following html:

```
 <div id="myID" class="xy za">...</div>
```

all browsers are absolutely ignoring the following css:

```
 #myID{style: any !important;}
```

because there are styles loaded for:

```
 #myID.xy.za{ ... }
```

important note: .xa.za are random classes, which alternate for every single user whyle extermal widget is loading, so i can't grep them.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it has a parent of eg. class `parent`, maybe you can try `.parent #myID{ // Rules here }` or similar

Comment: Please show a [mcve] where you have both rules, and the one in question is ignored.

Comment: And you should never use `!important`. The `!important` modifier results in hard to manage css code.

Comment: I found out, that the #myID Element is within a shadow DOM, so i can't access it via my css.

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that the #myID Element is within a shadow DOM, so i can't access it via my css.

Comment: This might be of interest for you [Override styles in a shadow-root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625017/override-styles-in-a-shadow-root-element)

Comment: This ist the way i got it:  ```var responeEl = document.querySelector('#myID').shadowRoot.querySelector('.myClass');  
jQuery(responeEl).css("font-size", "19pt");```

Answer (score 0):

This example I made works fine for me.

There's probably something else in your CSS that overrides with `!important` your styles for `#myID`

```css
#myID {
  color: red !important;
  font-size: 30px !important;
  font-family: arial !important;
}

#myID.xy.za {
  color: green;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: courier;  
}
```

```html
<div id="myID" class="xy za">
This is your div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
#myID {
  color: red !important;
  font-size: 30px !important;
  font-family: arial !important;
}
</style>


<div id="myID" class="xy za" style= " color: green !important;font-size: 12px !important; font-family: courier !important;  ">
This is your div
</div>
```

Try  In-line css !!