# How to remove in input (safari) email and password saved suggestion box?

Tags: html, email, input, safari, passwords

[SAFARI SUGGESTION KEYBOX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAhIt.png)

There is an annoying box with key on input's right, can't remove it on safari. Help please.
You can SEE IMAGE and get the point.

```
        <div>
          <label for="email">email:</label>
          <input
            name="email"
            id="user-email"
            autofocus
            required
            type="email"
            autocomplete="new-email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="password">password:</label>
          <input
            name="password"
            id="user-password"
            required
            minlength="8"
            type="password"
            autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
```

Tried autocomplete="new-email" ; autocomplete="off", but it deals with different things than I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to override styles defined in the shadow dom

e.g.

```
input::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns%3D\"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg\" …2.467 2.521c.171.171.36.256.565.256z\" opacity%3D\".75\"%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
margin-left: 2px;
margin-right: 1px;
mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: auto;
-webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

More info on that here.

[Override styles in a shadow-root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625017/override-styles-in-a-shadow-root-element)

Also, in my case inline style is being applied depending on focus e.g.

```
display: block !important;
```

and

```
display: none !important;
```

The fact it uses `!important` makes this a little trickier to override if you simply wanted to hide it.

My feeling is safari adds these values depending on the context, i.e. if text input prepends password in same fieldset it assumes that it is a user name, and adds the icon to allow you to fill with key chain or similar.