# CSS Selector over Circle element inside SVG inside Shadow DOM not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

[image]

I just want to add the `stroke` property to it to change the progress ring color. This circle is generated by a third party library and I have no control over it. I have been trying four hours different options but none of them work:

```
svg::part(indeterminate-indicator-1) {
    color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
}

slot[name='indeterminate'] {
    color: black !important;
    opacity: 1;
}

slot[name=indeterminate] {
    width: 400px;
    stroke: black !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
}

div > span > fluent-progress-ring[_bl_b6bfd787-f5d6-4b24-8906-74e2ca992e1c] > slot[name='indeterminate'] {
    width: 400px;
    stroke: black !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
}
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong? Is it possible to change the style inside a shadow root?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625017/override-styles-in-a-shadow-root-element

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will check that solution but, if possible I would like to tweak it without Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after many tries with:

`fluent-progress-ring::part(indeterminate-indicator-1) { stroke: blue !important;}`