# Style an element inside a shadow dom

Tags: css, shadow-dom

I'm applying a custom CSS style on top of an application of which I can't modify the code.

Previously the DOM was like this:

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

and I was modifying it easily with `.foo .bar`.

But they released a new version of the app and now the child is in a shadow DOM:

```html
<div class="foo">
  #shadow-root
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

and obviously my previous selector does not work anymore. How can I reach this `.bar`, only if it is inside a `.foo`? I read about ::part(), but I can't add `part="bar"` on the DOM element. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Currently with only CSS, if `part` is not used, there is no way to **target** the child elements from the outside. This is intended and the [motivation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shadow-parts/#motivation) for this is to allow the Shadow DOM creator to fully control what are exposed to be styled outside.

However, if JavaScript is allowed and the Shadow DOM is created with mode `open`, you can target the child element using `shadowRoot.querySelector`.

```js
const host = document.querySelector("#host");
const shadow = host.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "bar";
div.textContent = "I'm in the shadow DOM";
shadow.appendChild(div);


document.querySelector("#host").shadowRoot.querySelector(".bar").style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div id="host" class="foo"></div>
```

You can also [inject styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47633167/9107694) that includes rules that targets the `bar` using JavaScript, but again only when the mode is `open`.

Otherwise, you'll have to check if the app is using custom properties on the styles you need to customize or style the Shadow DOM using inherited properties.