# How to override a style of a library component in React app css?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

EDIT: Here's [stackblitz for example app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hrgp9a?file=src%2FMyComponent%2FMyComponent.module.css)
EDIT 2: See my answer for simple solution

I have a React component that shows an [alert component](https://github.com/trimble-oss/modus-web-components/blob/main/stencil-workspace/src/components/modus-alert/modus-alert.tsx) with the [scss](https://github.com/trimble-oss/modus-web-components/blob/main/stencil-workspace/src/components/modus-alert/modus-alert.scss).

```
export function MyComponent() {
  return (
     <div className={styles.alert}>
       <ModusAlert message={'Some message'}></ModusAlert>
     </div>
  );
}
```

MyComponent.module.css

```
.alert {
  width: 390px;
  margin-top: 182px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
```

Now I need to change color and background-color among other things. When I look at the style in DevTools for the label inside the alert there's a style below.

**Style in DevTools:**

```
div.alert .message {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Editing that style in DevTools to the style below changes the appearance of the web page.

**Edited style in DevTools (changes appearance):**

```
div.alert .message {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
}
```

However, if I add that style from DevTools to my component's CSS, it doesn't work.

**Edited style from DevTools added to CSS (does NOT change appearance):**

```
div.alert .message {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
}
```

So how this should be done? Below is the element style for div that contains the message of alert:

[image]

Comment: The best way of injecting custom style into a component of a library is using its way, like using the `className` prop etc. By the way, now, please put another screenshot of your DevTools after your custom CSS in your own file. Because I guess the above screenshot is the element's style before your modification

Comment: I think the screenshot was taken when my  css already contained `div.alert .message` style. I tried now and it looks exactly the same. The style is shown like that in DevTools but it doesn't contain the color. So adding that to css has no effect.

Comment: Dear @charm, It's not voodoo, it's so simple. Your CSS wasn't loaded because of an unknown issue. Go and find that. I think you must show us how you imported your CSS and how you used the library component. The description of the question post needs to be changed.

Comment: It's not voodoo, but all styles in same file work except `div.alert .message` which probably means that it's not correct.

Comment: Please leave a minimal re-production of your issue. I'm so curious about this issue. Upload it on Github or GitLab please.

Comment: @AmerllicA: I created now a stackblitz app because I knew how to do it fast. The link is in the question. Let me know if you need somethings else. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the issue you're encountering might be related to the Shadow DOM. This reference on Stack Overflow could be really helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47625017/20449015.

Comment: Thanks @MDHasanPatwary for your comment. Pls see my answer for simple solution

Answer (score 0):

you can override a css with make a selector more precise than the one you want override, or with the key-word "important".
(if I correctly understand the problem you ask)

```
/* selector more precise for the div */
div.alert:has(>.message) { color: white; }

/* important */
div.alert { color: white !important; }
```

Comment: I'm trying to change color for the external library component in my own css file.

Comment: if your own css file is not apply change over the external library, it can be :
- the new css selector add is lower priority than the library.
- the new file css is not link to the page.
- or the browser cash is taking the older vertion of your css file.

Comment: Thought I commented already but this solution doesn't override the style.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below solution? Hope it will work for you.

You have written CSS code in `MyComponent.module.css`, which is intended to work only in the elements of the same component. However, you have used the `ModusAlert` library for the alert, which is another component.

To resolve this, you need to move your custom CSS related to `ModusAlert` into the global CSS/SCSS file such as `global.css` or `global.scss`, rather than any other `*.module.css` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I need to override ONLY for MyComponent though. Everywhere else it should look normal. Pls have a look at stackblitz link I added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must know about [`Shadow DOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM) and its usage. This *Modus* library I think was developed by using Shadow DOM to avoid CSS conflict and you are so lucky because its Shadow DOM is open and by using **JS PATH** it would be possible to have some styles modification. So, if you want to modify the styles you must use the following trick:

```js
// Use a JS PATH to reach the container of the `shadow root`
// Your case is like the following

const alertWrapper = document.querySelector("#root > div.my-alert > modus-alert");

const alertContent = alertWrapper.shadowRoot.querySelector('div.alert .message');

alertContent.style.color = 'red';
```

For more information have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625017/override-styles-in-a-shadow-root-element)

-- Update (based on the [reproduction link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hrgp9a?file=src%2FMyComponent%2FMyComponent.module.css)):

You need to use an `useEffect` to implement your change, pay attention the following code:

```
import { ModusAlert } from '@trimble-oss/modus-react-components';
import './MyComponent.css';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function overrideStyle(): void {
  // Use a JS PATH to reach the container of the `shadow root`
  // Your case is like the following
  const alertWrapper = document.querySelector(
    '#root > div.my-alert > modus-alert'
  );
  const alertContent =
    alertWrapper?.shadowRoot?.querySelector('div.alert .message');

  if (alertContent) {
    (alertContent as any).style.color = 'red';
  }
}

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    overrideStyle();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="my-alert">
      <ModusAlert message={'Style of this should be overridden'}></ModusAlert>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Fast comment before leaving until tomorrow: the quesrySelector returns null. I'll have a look at the post you linked when I come back tomorrow.

Comment: @charm, Feel free to edit the querySelector string argument. Just like I said, you must select the wrapper of `shadow-root`.

Comment: Thanks, but I found a simple solution for this. Pls see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the easiest way to override the alert color seems to be setting the css custom properties / css variables used in the 3rd party library. The appropriate variables can be found from the [component style file](https://stencil-workspace/src/components/modus-alert/modus-alert.vars.scss). So changing the existing style in MyComponent.module.css:

```
.alert {
  width: 390px;
  margin-top: 182px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  --modus-alert-primary-color: white;
}
```

Comment: It is not a proper way to change the color of a design system to modify only one part. Still I think you must directly change the color by using JS PATH. Your mistake about usage of my solution was avoiding to use `useEffect`. I just updated my answer.