# Is it possible to hide the engagement buttons from an embedded tweet?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter

I would like to embed tweets but without the engagement buttons, i.e. reply, retweet and like.

I have seen you can do this with the follow button:

[Remove follow button from embedded tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726344/remove-follow-button-from-embedded-tweet)

I'm struggling to figure out how to do it for the buttons though.

How can I do this?

I tried:

```
<style>
.TweetAction { display: none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to this with `jQuery`.

```
jQuery('idOrClass').contents().find('.TweetAction').hide();
```

You just need to replace `idOrClass` with your `#id` or `.class`. This will go into the `iframe` and find every `.TweetAction` in it and hide it.

**EDIT:**

You need to wait till the `iframe` is loaded fully.

Try this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('idOrClass').contents().find('.TweetAction').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to be working. I tried ```<script>
jQuery('.EmbeddedTweet-tweet').contents().find('.TweetAction').hide();
</script>``` which is the main class of the widget

Comment: Do you have jQuery enabled? Maybe use `$` instead of `jQuery`.

Comment: If not, check if `.EmbeddedTweet-tweet` is the `class` of the `iframe`. You need to select the `iframe`, not a parent or child div.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not even seeing an iframe

Comment: How is it embedded then? Do you maybe have a link where I can see your implementation?

Comment: It just seems to be pulling to data and injecting it into the page - using the standard embed script you get from twitter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162081/discussion-between-patrick-mlr-and-adders).